# SQL QUERY: Fetch many locations from MySQL, geocode with, then update records with lat / long

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I have a series of locations saved in a database and I need to fetch them all, geocode them, then put the lat / long back into the database. I'm using Pymysql to do this and have the following code but really not sure how to put the SQL query together.

I've currently got the following (I know the query is wrong!)

```
def geocode():
rows = myCursor.execute("SELECT location, id FROM jobs WHERE latitude IS NULL").fetchall()
for location in rows:
    latitude = geocoder.google(location).lat
    longitude = geocoder.google(location).lng
    myCursor.execute("UPDATE jobs SET latitude= %s, longitude =%s WHERE id=id",(latitude, longitude))
    connection.commit()
    print ("Locations geocoded")
```

As always, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The SELECT appears to be redundant

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
myCursor.execute("UPDATE jobs SET latitude= %s, longitude =%s WHERE id=%s;" % (latitude, longitude, id))
```